# How to use with credentials: true with TanStack Query fetch

Tags: credentials, react-query, httpcookie

Previously I used axios request withcredentials:true to get the cookie from server site when I started to to use useQuery of TanStack Query/react Query to fetch data, I couldn't be able to sent withCredentials: true. So I couldn't get any cookie from server site. Can anyone help me how to sent withCredentials when I'm fetching with useQuery of TanStack Query?

I have been tried to get answer that how to use React Query or TanStack query with Credentials.

Answer (score 2):

React query doesn't perform any fetching, you can keep using axios.

```js
const { data } = useQuery([some, key], async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get('SOME_URL', { withCredentials: true })
    return data
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Jakub, you're answer got me unstuck. What is react-query used for?

Comment: It is used to manage async state, which usually but not exclusively comes from making requests, and the relation to UI - loading, errors, deduplication, retries, background sync and others.